Odd visual behaviour with React Framer motion?
I'm experiencing an unexpected visual behavior when using React Framer motion AnimatePresence component. The actual behavior differs from what I'm expecting.
Expected Behavior:

Actual Behavior:
The text "React" disappears abruptly when using AnimatePresence. You can see the actual behavior:
Here's a minimal reproducible example:
import { motion, AnimatePresence } from "framer-motion";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(true);
  const TRANSITION_VARIENTS = {
    initial: {
      opacity: 0,
      y: 10,
    },
    idle: {
      opacity: 1,
      y: 0,
    },
    end: {
      opacity: 0,
      y: 10,
    },
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" onChange={() => setState(!state)} />
      </div>
      <div
        style={{
          width: "100vh",
          display: "flex",
        }}
      >
        <AnimatePresence mode="wait">
          {state && (
            <motion.span
              key="welcome-to"
              variants={TRANSITION_VARIENTS}
              initial="initial"
              animate="idle"
              exit="end"
              transition={{ type: "spring", bounce: 0, delay: 0.5 }}
            >
              Hello To{" "}
            </motion.span>
          )}
          <motion.span
            key="react"
            layoutId="react"
            variants={TRANSITION_VARIENTS}
            initial="initial"
            animate="idle"
            style={{
              color: "red",
            }}
            transition={{ type: "spring", bounce: 0 }}
          >
            React
          </motion.span>
          {!state && (
            <motion.span
              key="for-corporate"
              variants={TRANSITION_VARIENTS}
              initial="initial"
              animate="idle"
              exit="end"
              transition={{ type: "spring", bounce: 0, delay: 0.5 }}
            >
              {" "}
              for Corporate
            </motion.span>
          )}
        </AnimatePresence>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

Environment:
React version: 18.2.0
Framer-motion version: 11.5.4
Why is the text "React" disappearing abruptly instead of fading smoothly when using AnimatePresence? How can I achieve the expected smooth fade-in and fade-out effect?
Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.
